# Where is Polaris?

Tags: the-secret-world

The General and Looking for Group chat is spammed *constantly* with people looking for teammates to do a dungeon called "Polaris". From their messages, it seems that QL3 is about an appropriate time to start running that dungeon.

I'm approaching QL3, so I would like to know where to look if I decide to give this dungeon a go.

Where is Polaris?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find the quest near the top edge of the **Kingsmouth** map. There are two quest givers with a handful of normal quests, along with the dungeon quest for Polaris, and the Helicopter that will take you to the instance.

[image: Entrance to Polaris]

Comment: Any chance you could do a screenshot + freehand circle dealy?

Comment: When I log in to TSW in a bit I can if somebody doesn't beat me to it. They should be pretty clearly visible on your minimap -  the two NPC's furthest to the NE.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't see 2 NPCs in the Northeast of Kingsmouth.

Comment: Kingsmouth the zone, not the town.

Answer (score -3):

Polaris is great. You can find it if you click at a helicopter in kingsmouth ;)